# ApplicationUserContext is null in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, null, roles, account

I came accross something out of my world today. 
Basically, I'm using the default ApplicationUserContext included in EntityFramework, and somehow, when I add a role to a User, the subject needs to logout for the roles to get updated. In fact, it is normal because roles are stored in a cookie in which the infos are loaded every 30 minutes, or everytime the user signs in.

So in my case, I was trying to add the specific role to a user, using the role manager and then forcing a "resignin", aka Logout then Login.

```
_userManager.AddToRole(UserID, "the role of the world");
ApplicationUser theUser = _userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

if (returnUrl != null)
 {
    AccountController ac = new AccountController();
    await ac.Relogin(theUser);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
 }
```

Now you see, I created a new instance of the AccountController since I was in an other controller and called the method "Relogin(User)"

```
    public async Task Relogin(ApplicationUser _user)
    {
        await SignInAsync(_user, false);
    }
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
    }
```

Now when I run the code, I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. On this code :

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

Which basically mean that my HttpContext is null... I tried even getting the HttpContext in my controller and sending in as a parameter like this. It was not null in the controller but as soon as it went in AccountController, the userManager became null... what is happening?

```
public async Task Relogin(ApplicationUserManager _userManager)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of the `AccountController`?  Why not just call `SignInAsync` and then redirect?

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that since the beginning! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use async/await, the work is off loaded to another thread. The reason why HttpContext is null, is because you're no longer on the request thread anymore and thus the current HttpContext instance is not reachable (Thread Static).

To confirm, remove the async/await and try.

As quick work around, you can pass the reference to `AuthenticationManager` as a parameter argument.

Comment: I've sent the reference to AuthenticationManager, it worked as a quick fix.